# Why the watermark would not be processed while lastOutputStreamStatus.isActive() and channelStatuses[channelIndex].streamStatus.isActive()?

Tags: java, apache-flink

The `if` condition of this `inputWatermark` method confused me.

Why the input watermark would be ignored?

Can the watermark of that inputChannel be replaced by the input one without `lastOutputStreamStatus.isActive() && channelStatuses[channelIndex].streamStatus.isActive()`?

```java
public void inputWatermark(Watermark watermark, int channelIndex, DataOutput<?> output)
        throws Exception {
    // ignore the input watermark if its input channel, or all input channels are idle (i.e.
    // overall the valve is idle).
    if (lastOutputStreamStatus.isActive()
            && channelStatuses[channelIndex].streamStatus.isActive()) {
        long watermarkMillis = watermark.getTimestamp();

        // if the input watermark's value is less than the last received watermark for its input
        // channel, ignore it also.
        if (watermarkMillis > channelStatuses[channelIndex].watermark) {
            channelStatuses[channelIndex].watermark = watermarkMillis;

            // previously unaligned input channels are now aligned if its watermark has caught
            // up
            if (!channelStatuses[channelIndex].isWatermarkAligned
                    && watermarkMillis >= lastOutputWatermark) {
                channelStatuses[channelIndex].isWatermarkAligned = true;
            }

            // now, attempt to find a new min watermark across all aligned channels
            findAndOutputNewMinWatermarkAcrossAlignedChannels(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't want watermarks from idle channels to hold back the overall watermark; watermarks from idle channels should be ignored.